# Lower bound on smallest diagonal element

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, discrete-optimization, permutation-matrices

Let $\bf R$ be an $m \times m$ matrix with non-negative integer elements $r_{i,j}$, $0\leq r_{i,j} \leq n$ and $n=km$ (k is a positive integer), with the property $\sum_ir_{i,j}=\sum_jr_{i,j}=n$, i.e., every column and every row of $\bf R$ sums to $n$. I am interested in a lower bound for the following.

$$\underset{{\bf \Pi}} {\max} \underset{i \in [m]}{\min}\ \left( {\bf R} {\bf \Pi} \right)_{ii} $$

where $\bf \Pi$ is a permutation matrix and $[m] := \{1, 2, \dots, m\}$. In other words, a lower bound for the smallest diagonal value of ${\bf R \Pi}^*$, where

$$ {\bf \Pi}^* := \underset{{\bf \Pi}} {\operatorname{argmax}} \underset{i \in [m]}{\min} \left( {\bf R} {\bf \Pi} \right)_{ii} $$

In particular, I want to show that $n\,/\,m$ is a lower bound for all matrices $\bf R$ (for $m = 2$ this is easy to show by covering all possibilities). The coupling of the columns and the rows seems to make it, however, very tedious in arbitrary dimensions $m$, and I haven't been able to construct a counter example either.

Any hints, on a strategy to show this would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
The problem above is related to the following problem:

Suppose you have an $n\times m$ matrix $\bf Y$, where every row of $\bf Y$ is a permutation of [m], meaning
$$\bf Y = \begin{pmatrix}\pi_1([m])\\\pi_2([m])\\\vdots\\\pi_n([m])\end{pmatrix},$$ where $\pi_i$ is some permutation of $[m]$ and $i = 1,\dots,n$. Let the columns of $\bf Y $ be denoted as ${\bf y}_j,\:j = 1,\dots,m$. Suppose $n = km$, where k is a positive integer. Take for example the values $k = 2$ and $m=4$ with some corresponding matrix
$$\bf Y = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
3&2&1&4\\
4&2&1&3\\
1&4&3&2\\
2&1&3&4\\
1&3&4&2\\
2&4&3&1\\
3&4&2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If we were to select only one type of digit for every column of $\bf Y$, such that every digit has been selected **exactly once** (e.g., if I have selected 3 in ${\bf y}_1$ I cannot select it in another ${\bf y}_j,\:j\neq1$), is there a selection such that every  digit appears in its respective column at least $k$ times.

My hypothesis is that it is, since for $k=1$ it is trivial to see that every digit has to appear at least once. I am not sure if I can argue that since it holds for one "elementary block" of size $m \times m$ it holds for all integers $k$ (via induction).

For visualization I have marked two possible selections in the example from above

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&{\bf 2}&3&{\bf 4}\\
{\bf 3}&{\bf 2}&{\bf 1}&{\bf 4}\\
4&{\bf 2}&{\bf 1}&3\\
1&4&3&2\\
2&1&3&{\bf 4}\\
1&3&4&2\\
2&4&3&1\\
{\bf 3}&4&2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{or}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf 1}&2&{\bf 3}&4\\
3&2&1&4\\
4&2&1&3\\
{\bf 1}&{\bf 4}&{\bf 3}&{\bf 2}\\
2&1&{\bf 3}&4\\
{\bf 1}&3&4&{\bf 2}\\
2&{\bf 4}&{\bf 3}&1\\
3&{\bf 4}&2&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Of course, there could be other selections. The values of the elements in $\bf R$ are then the numbers of occurrence of each digit in every column of $\bf Y$.

Comment: Have you considered generalizing?  Say, solving for any $m \times m$ matrix? This may be tractable

Comment: Are you acquainted with the [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307636/91764)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! By generalizing you mean considering any doubly stochastic matrix, rather than those with values on a grid? I am uncertain if the bound would hold in that case, but might as well give it a shot

Comment: No, I meant that $\bf R$ does not need to be so special.  The relaxation should work for any square matrix.  I might be missing something, however

Comment: I see, the same relaxation that Youem has proposed in his post?

Comment: Probably. I did not review it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be written as

\begin{align}
\max_{t,\, \mathbf \Pi} \;& t\\
\text{subject to: }&& \sum_{j=1}^m \mathbf \Pi_{i,j}\mathbf R_{j,i} - t&\ge 0,&&\forall i=1,\ldots,m\\
&&\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf \Pi_{i,j} &=1,&&\forall i=1,\ldots,m\\
&&\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf \Pi_{i,j} &=1,&&\forall j=1,\ldots,m\\
&&\mathbf \Pi_{i,j} &\ge 0,&&\forall i,j=1,\ldots,m\\
\end{align}

By duality it is equivalent to:

\begin{align}
\min_{\lambda,\, \mu,\, \delta} \;& \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i + \sum_{j=1}^m \delta_j\\
\text{subject to: }&& \lambda_i + \delta_j - \mathbf R_{j,i}\mu_{i} &\ge 0,&&\forall i,j=1,\ldots,m\\
&& \sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i &=1\\
&& \mu_i &\ge 0 &&\forall i=1,\ldots,m
\end{align}

From the last it is not hard to prove your lower bound.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow the first constraint of the primal problem... shouldn't it be R_ii in the first constraint? Also, why is the summation necessary

Comment: It should be $(\Pi R)_{ii}$ which is the sum that I wrote.